# mem access violation

Tags: c++

I was wondering how this piece of code gives a memory access violation?

```
{
   Vector3f *a = new Vector3f [10];
   Vector3f *b = a;
   b[9] = Vector3f (2,3,4);
   delete[] a;
   a = new Vector3f [10];
   b[4] = Vector3f (1,2,3);
   delete[] a;
}
```

Comment: b still points to the "old" a.

Comment: note: what OS are you using? you are lucky that it didn't silently fail..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `b` still points to the same array as `a` when you call `delete[] a`, and then you try to use that memory with `b[4]`.

```
Vector3f *a = new Vector3f [10]; // a initialised to a memory block x
Vector3f *b = a;                 // b initialised to point to x also
b[9] = Vector3f (2,3,4);         // x[9] is assigned a new vector
delete[] a;                      // x is deallocated
a = new Vector3f [10];           // a is assigned a new memory block y
b[4] = Vector3f (1,2,3);         // x is used (b still points to x)
                                 // x was deallocated and this causes segfault
delete[] a;                      // y is deallocated
```

Answer (score 3):

it this line:

```
b[4] = Vector3f (1,2,3);
```

`b` is still pointing to the old, freed `a`.

Answer (score 3):

`b` points to the first-deleted `a` (i.e. `b` doesn't point to the *newly allocated* `a`), so when you try and use `b` again after deleting the memory that it points to, you are invoking undefined behaviour, and in this instance, it is giving you a memory access violation.